# iPhone iOS Dropbox how to pre-authenticate (link) an account for an app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, authentication, dropbox

I would like to try out an idea of using 1 centralized dropbox account to store data for one of my apps. This would be the kind of a "public" collaborative storage space.

To do so, I need to pre-authenticate the user to use a particular dropbox account. Is there a way for me to link a particular app to a dropbox account, and then include some kind of "pre-authenticated/authorized" tokens within the app to **allow the user to interact with my dropbox account without the need to login?**

Thank you!

Comment: just a heads up, that's probably against DropBox's terms of service if i had to guess. having a ton of different people using an app to log into 1 account could cause issues (concurrency) too. but to do it, just hardcode the username and password into the app and login with it.

Comment: +1 @JesseNaugher. It might still work though... but for reference, I use Amazon's S3 service, this way I can control my app "user" and easily revoke it if needs be, and set all the required permissions through Amazon IAM. Good luck :)